# Custom Landscape Layout (Master->Detail) when using Jetpack Navigation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack, landscape-portrait

I'm trying to create a Master-Detail app that should only show MasterView and DetailView next to eachother when the phone is in landscape mode: [Master][Detail]

If the phone is in portrait mode, only one of the two fragments is supposed to be visible, either [Master] or [Detail].

I've found nothing so far about how I can do this using Jetpack Navigation, I only found stuff for FragmentManager.

Is this even possible when using Jetpack Navigation?

I've tried creating a custom landscape layout, but I'm struggling with the navHostFragment. Should I create a separate NavGraph? How can I integrate showing both fragments next to eachother in the NavGraph?

Comment: This isn't a recommended pattern at all as per the [design for different form factors](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-form-factors) (which specifically states that "you should have each screen in your app take full advantage of the window real estate available to you.") and [responsive patterns guidelines](https://material.io/design/layout/component-behavior.html#responsive-patterns).

Comment: so we're only supposed to use the MasterDetail layout next to each other when the screen size increases (use on tablets etc)?

Comment: Like I said, that isn't one of the recommended patterns at *any* screen size.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Yet Calendar, Mail, Messages, and Settings all seem to use some form of it? Not to mention Contacts quite frankly looks pretty bad without it at larger screen sizes. Seems like a pretty common and useful design pattern to include support for... ‍♂️